# get information from an other entity

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have two entities "OfferStage and Entreprise" with relation ManyToOne and OneToMany, and for the display of the list of "offrestage" I like to display the Logo of each "Entreprise"

**Entity/OffreStage**

```
class OffreStage
{
 /...

/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Entreprise",      inversedBy="offres", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entreprise_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

protected $entreprise;
```

**Entity/Entreprise**

```
class Entreprise extends User
{
/..
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Gestion\StageBundle\Entity\OffreStage", mappedBy="entreprise")
 */
protected $offres;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true) 
 */
protected $path;
```

**Controller**

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('FrontBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function listeStagesShowAction()
    {  
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $offreStages = $em->getRepository('StageBundle:OffreStage')-    >findAll();



        return $this->render('FrontBundle:Stage:listeStage.html.twig',      array(
            'offreStages' => $offreStages,

        ));
}    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? We won't write your code, but we will be happy to solve any problems you may encounter.
You may want to look at the sf2 documentation about the view http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/quick_tour/the_view.html

Comment: my problem that I like to access for the path of the Logo of the Entity "Entreprise"

Comment: Yes and this is why you want to take a look at the link I gave you. You send an object in the view, and you can use this object in the twig file with all this properties, relations, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it just problem from database , it found data with null value